# What is wrong in my SSH key generation?

Tags: command-line, ssh

I'm trying to generate a new SSH key:

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "newkey"
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/z/.ssh/id_rsa): newkey
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
Your identification has been saved in newkey.
Your public key has been saved in newkey.pub.
```

but `.ssh/` is still the same:

```
ls ~/.ssh/*.pub
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The key is generated in your current working directory i.e. the directory you were in while running the command.

The prompt

```
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/z/.ssh/id_rsa):
```

will default to the file `~/.ssh/id_rsa` if you don't provide anything.

If you give an input, that will be treated as:

- Full (absolute) path to the end filename if starts with `/`
- Relative to the `$PWD` if the path is relative (does not start with `/`)

So check your current working directory, not `~/.ssh/`.

Answer (score 8):

You entered a relative path, not an absolute path, so the key will be saved in your present working directory. Try instead entering `/home/z/.ssh/newkey`, or just look for the public and private keys in your current directory and move them to `~/.ssh`.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the line with:`Enter file in which save the key`, where you answered `newkey`.
As you can see in the example `(/home/z/.ssh/id_rsa)`, you need to enter the path too! As you entered `newkey`, it means `./newkey` and `./newkey.pub`. So use `ls` in the current directory and you will see those files!